# Converting an objects x/y value into an int

Tags: c#, winforms, rounding

I have a simply block of code, that when you mouse up, it snaps an object to the nearest 30/30 grid.

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int gridCubeWidth = 30;
    int gridCubeHeight = 30;

    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {                                       
        double newX = Math.Round(pictureBox1.Left / (double)gridCubeWidth) * 
            (double)gridCubeWidth;

        pictureBox1.Left = (int)newX;

        double newY = Math.Round(pictureBox1.Top / (double)gridCubeHeight) * 
            (double)gridCubeHeight;

        pictureBox1.Top = (int)newY;
    }
}
```

This is the only way I managed to get this to work, because from what I can tell, pictureBox1.left/top are in the form of "Doubles", which breaks my Math.Round.

I've tried changing everything to be Int, and adding (Int) in front of the pictureBox1.Left, but it doesn't seem to change this.

```
int newX = Math.Round((int)pictureBox1.Left / gridCubeWidth) * gridCubeWidth;
pictureBox1.Left = newX;
```

I feel like what I'm doing is somewhat very redundant, converting everything to Doubles, then back to an Int, and that there'd be a much simpler way to achieve this.

My main question, is why doesn't `(int)pictureBox1.Left` seem to convert this value into an Int

Comment: How does using a double "break" Math.Round()?

Comment: If you read the documentation (or look at the property in the designer), you'll see that `PictureBox.Left` (which comes from the `Control` class) is an `int`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.left?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Try to parse it in this way: int.Parse(pictureBox1.Left)

Comment: When I run the `(int)pictureBox1.left` I get this result from the debugger `The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Math.Round(double)' and 'Math.Round(decimal)'`

Comment: They need to be `double` otherwise there'd be nothing to round; `int / int = int`.  Why not just declare your variables as `double` in the first place to avoid the casts?  They could even be `const`.  `const double gridCubeWidth = 30D;`

Comment: `Math.Round` expects an argument of type `double` or `decimal`. If you pass in `(int * double)`, it will work just fine because there's an implicit conversion between `int` and `double`. Your question is not clear.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The Left and Top properties are ints. I don't see why you need doubles. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.left?view=netframework-4.8

You should be able to do rounding like this: `int left = (pictureBox1.Left / 30) * 30;`

Comment: See, I thought this as well, but I'm getting `The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Math.Round(double)' and 'Math.Round(decimal)'` with Math.Round()

Comment: My code sample does NOT have a Math.Round() call, you don't need that.

Comment: Hmm, I guess then I don't need to use Math.Round() at all then, as without it, per your example, it seems to work fine without the need to convert to/from Double

Comment: @level42 That won't "snap ... to the **nearest** 30/30 grid", though.  If `pictureBox1.Left` is `29` then `(pictureBox1.Left / 30) * 30` becomes `(29 / 30) * 30` becomes `0 * 30` which, of course, equals `0`.  That's a floor function, not "nearest".

Comment: @BACON I appreciate the feedback, I'll double check my math.

Comment: Just add half the grid size, like `((left+15)/30)*30` and then it will be snappy.